# neo4j cypher: how to change the type of a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can't find a way to change a relationship type in Cypher. Is this operation possible at all? If not: what's the best way achieve this result?

Comment: If you use the [apoc procedures plugin](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) you can simply use `call apoc.refactor.setType(rel, 'NEW-TYPE')` to easily change the relationship type. It automatically does what you would have to manually do otherwise (as per the answers).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct change of rel-type possible at the moment.

You can do:

```
MATCH (n:User {name:"foo"})-[r:REL]->(m:User {name:"bar"})
CREATE (n)-[r2:NEWREL]->(m)
// copy properties, if necessary
SET r2 = r
WITH r
DELETE r
```

Comment: brilliant! (added the `WITH` otherwise the query was failing)

Comment: Excellent answer. But, this only deletes relationship & return `ID` of that relationship & doesn't show updated relationship until `WITH` clause is added to it, as commented above & answered by @LoveTW. I'll give you `+1` for **fastest answer**.

Answer (score 14):

The answer from `Michael Hunger` is correct but it still need `with` in this cypher query.
`WITH` can be used when you want to switch different operation in one cypher query.
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-with.html

```
MATCH (n:User {name:"foo"})-[r:REL]->(m:User {name:"bar"})
CREATE (n)-[r2:NEWREL]->(m)
SET r2 = r
WITH r
DELETE r
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't, the type of a relationship is constitutive or essential, as opposed to node labels which are arbitrary bags to group nodes. (See [this q/a for an analogy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542802/change-node-label-in-neo4j/22570633).) You have to create the new relationship, delete the old (and copy properties if there are any).

Answer (score 1):

I would simply delete the relationship and create a new one:

```
MATCH (a) - [r:OLD_RELATION] -> (b)
DELETE r
CREATE (a) - [:NEW_RELATION] -> (b)
```

Comment: properties of the relation will be lost

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Neo4j 4.2.5 recently.

I use **[APOC apoc.refactor.setType](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/set-relationship-type/)** to set the relationship types.

Read the documentation and install the plugin.

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

I use the following when modifying it.

```
match (from:Label1 { prop: 1 })-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(to:Label2 { prop: 2 })
with from, r, to
create (from)-[:NEW_RELATIONSHIP]->(to)
with r
delete r
```