# Change NEO4j Edge Type Label

Tags: neo4j

> How do I change an existing edge type on Neo4j. I am already able to
>   change my existing node type with no issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [neo4j cypher: how to change the type of a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670369/neo4j-cypher-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-relationship)

Comment: Duplicate, but make sure you see the comment on the linked question itself on using `apoc.refactor.setType()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to InverseFalcon for the answer. :)

`apoc.refactor.setType()` will change the edge type label. Tried and tested.