# Change node label from id to name

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Very new to Cypher and Neo4j so please excuse my ignorance and misuse of terms. I am looking to change the label of a node from the ID to the property name (see image below). I used the following code to load the data from CSV.

```
load csv with headers from "file:///Goal.csv" as row
create (g:Goal) set g.name = row.goalName
```

Is there a way to change the label from the ID to the name property? I have tried the solution in the link below but it did not provide what I am looking for. Ultimately I would like the node to show the name information (i.e. reduce fuel, green, etc.)

[Change node label in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542802/change-node-label-in-neo4j)

[image: Node graph - label as ID not name]

Comment: You mean just in the Neo4j Browser visualisation, for the nodes to show the contents of the name property instead of the node ID?

Comment: you could give this a little read

https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-browser/

scroll down to "Styling Neo4j Browser Visualization"

Comment: Yes I would like to change the caption in the Browser visualization. I have looked at the styling as recommended, but am not setting where I can make the change. Is this something that can be done on import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dave Bennett's comment's right - [the docs](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-browser/#browser-styling) will help show all the visualisation customisations you can do but for this specific case:

- Click the node label above the graph visualisation you want to change - they're colour-coded
- Choose a new caption field underneath the graph

In this graph, let's change the caption of the yellow 'Location' nodes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you....that is so simple, feeling a tad silly now. Thank you for the help, much appreciated

Comment: It's really not very discoverable - I keep forgetting how to do it myself :D